# Menu Creation....at the place of Dialog Box

Tags: android

> Wanna create menu at the place of delete Dialog,which will contain open,delete,etc like options.Help me acc.ly.
>   New to Android and Java. :)

`new AlertDialog.Builder(this)`
   `.setTitle("Confirm Restore")` 
   `.setMessage("Do you want to restore this File?")`
   `.setPositiveButton("OK",` 
   `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {}`

Answer (score 0):

See 'Adding a list' at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

You cant show Menu options (by pressing menu key) when a dialog is visible.

Comment: yeah i know that ..........but i wanna create menu at the place of dialog....means removing dialog and then placing menu.so ,i need help for menu creation.Actually

Comment: instead of doing the fuzz to place menu on the middle of screen, i would suggest you to open a dialog interface with options on the press of menu-key. it simple